# How to choose a CNN model for a particular use case?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

So I am in the requirement gathering phase of implementing CNN project for a use case. I am eager to know how picking up a suitable model for the particular use case is done in the AI/ML industry. I saw there are a lot of CNN architectures but how to choose which architecture would suit my requirement?

Is it done only in a trial by error basis or are there any specific method for picking the right architecture? If it is a trial by error process, isnt it cumbersome? If we need to use only trial by error method, how long is it going to help us?

Comment: It depends. What kind of task you are currently working on ? . Image classification, Image segmentation, Super resolution, Object detection, etc has different approach.  There are too many scientific papers out there for computer vision field.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you will have some constraints that will help you narrow down on your options. For example, if you need to develop for mobile device your best bets are [MobileNets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04861) or [ShuffleNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01083) architectures. You can check each candidate model's performance on the [ILSVRC](http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/) validation set and have an idea of their relative performance. From there you can select the model that performed best within your constraints (training resource available, time/memory limitation during inference). If you use transfer learning, you will need to decide how many layers to freeze. Although that will depend on your training data (more data means you can fine-tune more layers without risk of overfitting) there is still some trials and erros involved. Then based on the amount of time and resources you have you can investigate other models.

Answer (score 0):

By saying architectures, if you mean

1. VGG16
2. Resnet (from microsoft)
3. Inception (from google) etc.,

All above are built by different groups to participate in [image-net wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageNet#History_of_the_ImageNet_challenge) challenge which happens every year. Every architecture corresponds to only one use case, **to classify images among 1000 different categories**.
So, I don't think architectures can be differentiated by use case.
That being said, you can consider architecture by following criteria,

1. Accuracy of models built using different architectures (Highest being best)
2. And also, how well it is generalizing on test/new incoming data, which is also very important.
3. Training time & GPU memory constraints (VGG16 is fairly simple and trains fast, but other two mentioned above would have many layers)
4. Complexity of the model

Comment: Yeah, I meant them only. I guess the second part of your answer is helpful, thanks. But if I cannot find any pretrained models for my use case, I need to pick a NN arch to train my own model, how will I choose the best NN arch for that? Is there a definite procedure? 

Do we need to carry out a trial by error process for picking the right arch?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no defined procedure for that. If you don't have any pre-trained model trained on similar use case as yours, you have to try out different architectures or customizing architecture, or you should build your own. And yes, final model is picked based on predictions of each architecture (by trail) and it depends on data and problem statement.

Comment: Are there any methods based on randomly picking hyper-parameters within an interval to slowly identify the “zone” where the optimal CNN models exist?